# React setState not working using event property

Tags: reactjs

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({
  productName: "",
  quantity: 0,
  basePrice: 0,
  sellPrice: 0,
})

const handleChange = (e) => {
  let fieldName = e.target.id;
  let fieldValue = e.target.value;
  setProduct({
    fieldName: fieldValue
  });
};
```

Code above doesnt seem to work. when i log fieldName however, it return `productName`.

I tried to explicitly use productName instead and its working

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  let fieldName = e.target.id;
  let fieldValue = e.target.value;
  setProduct({
    productName: fieldValue
  });
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on under the hood why the initial approach is not working?

PS reason i want to use e.target.id is because there are multiple fields that needs updating Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setter on the **[`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)** doesn't work like the **[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)** method on a React Class Component.

Setting just a particular field name would override the values of the other fields in the `product` Object and will set them to `undefined`.

You'll have to spread the existing `product` Object to get the values of the other fields and then only override the value of the field by using the `[]` notation to dynamically set the field name.

Something like this:

```
setProduct({ 
  ...product,
  [fieldName]: fieldValue 
});
```

Comment: Good to know! Didn't know about the difference between how `useState` replaces state and `setState` merges state until now. [Here's a link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables) to the particular section of documentation that mentions it.

Comment: been stuck on this for long time, i tried this as well before but without the [ ]. in my opinion, the most important part here is the [ ]. I guess somehow when a variable is put inside a [ ] bracket it like unwraps and get just the value? so it is becomes "productName" instead of "fieldName". Am I making any sense. anyway this is resolved now thank you

Answer (score 1):

React hooks works differently than the classic setState .

In **setState**, even if you set the one property and never mention the other properties, those properties will persist. e.g For state of name and email, if you do the setState for name, email value will be there, it won't be erased.

But in **useState**, the value won't be there. Similar to the previous example, if you set the name property, email will be erased i.e undefined. So either you can spread the old object to get the old values Or you can create separate states for individuals (e.g  useState for name and useState for email)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [store, setStore] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // console.log(e, e.target.name, e.target.value);
    setStore({...store,  [e.target.name]: e.target.value });   // Spreading
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label id="name">Name</label>
      <input
        name="name"
        type="text"
        htmlFor="name"
        value={store.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
      <br />
      <br />
      <label id="email">email</label>
      <input
        name="email"
        type="text"
        htmlFor="email"
        value={store.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another way

```
 const [name, setName] = useState("");
 const [email,setEmail]= useState("");

// handle the change handlers
```

Comment: Thanks tedd. I learned that in spread operator, the [ ] bracket is important . As you mentioned
 setStore({...store,  [e.target.name]: e.target.value });   // Spreading
without [ ] in the  [e.target.name], javascript will just add e.target.name to the end of the object. Somehow adding the [ ] bracket tells js to only look for the value inside of it but not necessarily make a new instance. Like a pseudo variable. Interesting.

Comment: PS im very new to programming and didnt this at school so my way of understanding may be weird to some. But i think i get it.

Comment: @JonathanChiong, yupp...it feels weird...but hey..through doing only..we will understand... :)